# Any Information in an Android app that should be deleted when pushing to github?

Tags: android, open-source

I'm thinking about pushing my Android app to github, but is there any information I should delete before I push it? (like in my project folder or some sort of hidden/embedded information)

Comment: You can see ``.gitignore`` file I'm using usually here; https://github.com/harism/android_effects/blob/master/.gitignore . So no, there's not many files you have to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure you don't have your keystore anywhere in your project structure
2. If you're using Google Maps or anything else with an API key, remove the API key.
3. If your email is part of a help page or something, remove it if you don't want it publicly visible.

Comment: @tomoari Please accept the answer if it answered your question